# Enhancing performance of SQL query

Tags: mysql, database, join, indexing, query-optimization

I am running a query on three tables `messages`, `message_recipients` and `users`.

Table structure of `messages` table:

```
id int pk
message_id int
message text
user_id int
...
```

Index for this table is on `user_id`, `message_id` and `id`.

Table structure of `message_recipients` table:

```
id int pk
message_id int
read_date datetime
user_id int
...
```

Index is on `id`, `message_id` and `user_id`.

Table structure of `users` table:

```
id int pk
display_name varchar
...
```

Index is on `id`.

I am running the following query against these tables:

```
SELECT 
    m.*, 
    if(m.user_id = 0, 'Campus Manager', u.display_name) AS name,
    mr.read_date, 
    IF(m1.message_id > 0 and m1.user_id=1, true, false) as replied 
FROM 
    messages m 
JOIN 
    message_recipients mr 
ON 
    mr.message_id = m.id 
LEFT JOIN 
    users u 
ON 
    u.UID = m.user_id 
LEFT JOIN 
    messages m1 
ON 
    m1.message_id = m.id 
WHERE 
    mr.user_id = 1 
AND 
    m.published = 1 
GROUP BY 
    mr.message_id 
ORDER BY 
    m.created DESC
```

`EXPLAIN` returns the following data for this query:
[image: Explain query result]

**UPDATE**
As suggested by @e4c5, I added new composite index on (published,user_id,created) and now the explain query shows this:
[image: Updated explain query]

How can this query be optimized by adding required indexes (if any) as it is taking lot of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to bring down the query time from 3 seconds to 0.1 second by adding a new index to `messages` and `message_recipients` table and changing the database engine of `messages` table to `MyISAM` from `InnoDB`.

Composite index `composite` added on these columns with respective order on `messages` table - `published, user_id, created`

Composite index `message_id_2` added on two columns on `message_recipients` table - `message_id, user_id`

**EXPLAIN Query now shows**

[image: EXPLAIN Query]

Answer (score 0):

- `GROUP BY` needs to list all the non-aggregated columns.  I suspect that would be a mess.  Why do you need `GROUP BY` at all?
- Why are you linking messages.id to messages_id?  Is this a hierarchical table, but the column names aren't like 'parent_id'?
- "Index is on id, message_id and user_id" -- is that one composite index or 3 single-column indexes?  (It makes a big difference.)  It would be better to show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` instead of ambiguously paraphrasing.
- Is user_id=1 prolific?  That is, are you expecting thousands of rows?  Is this query only a problem for him?
- Using `LEFT JOIN` implies that `m1.message_id` could be `NULL`, yet the reference to it seems to ignore that possibility.
- If this is a single table that contains a message thread -- both the main info about the thread and the individual responses, then I suggest it is a bad design.  (I made this mistake once upon a time.)  I think it iis better to have a table with one row per thread and another table with one row per comment.  1 thread : many comments.  So there would be a thread_id in the comment table.

Comment: Group by is necessary to avoid duplicates. It is a hierarchical table with the `id` of replied message going to `message_id`. No there are three individual indexes. No, the problem is with every user, not just single one. Yes `m1.message_id` can be `null`, which means the message has not been replied yet. There is nothing like message thread, just the `id` of message sent as reply to a particular message.